# writing regular expression for password validation

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working on input sanitation and want to write the regular expression for password validation. I was using OWASP ESAPI for the validation of the input parameters but I cant do that since regex provided for password validation by ESAPI is not satisfying all the conditions.

such as

•  8-20 characters using letters and numbers

•   Cannot have 3 or more consecutive identical letters, numbers, or special characters

•   Cannot contain a space

Optional:

•   One or more special characters, except for “ & ’ ⁄ < > [ \ ] { | } ~ ^ !

•   Case sensitive

PWASP ESAPI regex -`![CDATA[^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))(?!.*(.)\1{2,})[A-Za-z0-9!~<>,;:_=?*+#."&§%°()\|\[\]\-\$\^\@\/]{8,32}$]]`

I tried to modify it but i was not getting expected results as well as i am not super confidant with regex as i never used them before. How can i create a regex that can incorporate all the conditions?

Thank you

Comment: May I ask: why? Apart from >1 special char and 8+ chars all the constraints are actively bad.

Comment: code is related to legacy application

Comment: NIST recommendations surrounding passwords have changed. https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html 

Instead of looking to build password complexity into your tool.  Might be better to leverage a service to check if the password has been compromised and to use some sort of guidance tool to help your end users choose stronger passphrases.

Comment: You might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do not use RegEx for this, as it gets tedious to write, and even more tedious to maintain.

Preferably you'd look for a library that allows you to pass a configuration (something like [passay](https://github.com/vt-middleware/passay)).

If you don't want that you should use common string functions to check for length (`str.length()`, and existence of numbers and special characters (like `str.matches()`).

Not only will it be easier to maintain - it will also be faster since very complicated RegEx queries can quickly get quite slow.

Answer (score -1):

So i come up with solution but its in parts

so here are the regex for each condition

^((.)\1{3}) - Cannot have 3 or more consecutive identical letters, numbers, or special characters

[a-zA-Z0-9\S] - case sensitive cannot contain spaces and letters and numbers

[^ \“ & '< > [ /]{|}~^!] - One or more special characters, except for “ & ’ ⁄ < > [ \ ] { | } ~ ^ !

{7,20}$ - range

but if combine them all together they wont work as expected...

any suggestion?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer

Comment: i know i just added what i have found so far